# how to get div id to value from html file which is uploaded right now?

Tags: php, html, dom

i'm unable to get value form html file which is uploaded same time.

i have 2 files like this

index.html

```
<form action="uidserver.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    Select File:  
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>  
</form>
```

and this is second page uidserver.php

```
<?php  
$target_path = "files/";  
$target_path = $target_path.basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);   
  $newfilename = time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.' . end(explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "files/" . $newfilename)) {  
    echo "File uploaded successfully!  \n \r"; 

} else{  

    echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!";  
} 

$html = "http://domain.tld/uid/files/".$newfilename;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsById('cpBody_txt_Data_UserName');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

print $title;

?>
```

this code is exist in html file -

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="control-label">Display Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input name="ctl00$cpBody$txt_Data_UserName" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="MY NAME" maxlength="100" id="cpBody_txt_Data_UserName" tabindex="1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <span id="cpBody_vldReqUsername" class="error" style="display:none;">User Name Required</span>
        <span class="material-input"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

output is blank

but i want to get value of `cpBody_vldReqUsername` this id

and exist value is "MY NAME"

Comment: you need to put that `input` under `form` tag or use `jquery & ajax`

Comment: can u explain please with example

Comment: any one have solution ??

Comment: i actuly   need this coading $dom->getElementsById('cpBody_txt_Data_UserName');